Solving 1D Klein Gordon with null initial conditions
I want to solve the 1D Klein-Gordon equation for $u(t,z)$ and $t>0, z>0$
\begin{equation}
    \partial_{tt} u - \partial_{zz}u + k^2 u = 0,
\end{equation}
with the boundary conditions
\begin{align}
    u(t,z = 0) &= f(t)\theta(t), & u(t,z \to \infty) &\text{ is bounded},\\
    u(t = 0,z) &= 0, & \partial_t u(t=0,z) &= 0,
\end{align}
where $\theta(t)$ is Heaviside's Theta function. I also want $u=0$ for all $t<0$.
I have tried to use separation of variables $u(t,z)=T(t)Z(z)$, but I find that $T=0$ because of the initial conditions.
I have also tried to introduce $v(t,z) = u(t,z) - f(t)\theta(t) e^{-z}$, which gives us a PDE with a source, but with simpler boundary conditions. This led me to the result $u=0$, which doesn't look too good, as this equation should allow for non-zero solutions!
My question then is: how do I solve this equation?

Perhaps a Laplace transform in the $z$ direction would be useful. Or transforming coordinates to $p = x-t$ and $q=x+t$.

@whpowell96 right! I was doing the Laplace transform for $v$, but it was probably a but stupid. Thanks! The problem is that it will be pretty hard to untransform :(

Separation of variables only yields tractable solutions when the wife values are countable, which tends to occur when the domain is compact. I think integral transforms or characteristics are the only way to solve this problem

Try to solve PDE with Laplace transform
$$\mathcal{L}_t\left[k^2 u(t,z)+\frac{\partial ^2u(t,z)}{\partial t^2}-\frac{\partial ^2u(t,z)}{\partial z^2}\right](s)=k^2 U(s,z)+s^2 U(s,z)-s u(0,z)-U^{(0,2)}(s,z)-u^{(1,0)}(0,z)$$
With the initial conditions $u(0,z)=0, u^{(1,0)}(0,z)=0$ we get the ODE:
$$k^2 U(s,z)+s^2 U(s,z)-U^{(0,2)}(s,z)=0$$
with the boundary condition $U(s,0)=F(s)=\mathcal{L}_t[f(t)](s)$ we get the solution
$$U(s,z)=F(s) e^{-z \sqrt{k^2+s^2}}+c_1 e^{z \sqrt{k^2+s^2}}-c_1 e^{-z \sqrt{k^2+s^2}}$$
Because $U(s,z\to \infty)$ must be bounded, we choose $c_1=0$ and get the final solution
$$U(s,z)=F(s)\cdot e^{-z \sqrt{k^2+s^2}}$$
and
$$u(t,z)=\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[F(s)\cdot e^{-z \sqrt{k^2+s^2}}\right](t)$$
With
$$g(t)=\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[e^{-z \sqrt{k^2+s^2}}\right](t)=\delta(t-z)-\frac{\theta(t-z) k z J_1(k \sqrt{t^2-z^2})}{\sqrt{t^{2}-z^{2}}}$$
we finally obtain a convolution integral
$$u(t,z)= (f*g)(t)=\int_0^t f(t-\tau)\cdot g(\tau) d\tau= f(t-z)\theta(t-z)-k z\cdot \int_{0}^{t} f(t-\tau)\cdot \theta(\tau-z)\cdot \frac{J_1(k\sqrt{\tau^2-z^2})}{\sqrt{\tau^2-z^2}} d\tau$$
Example Propagation of sinesoidal pulse: $f(t)=(1-\theta (t-1))\sin(\pi t), k=\frac{1}{2}$

Because in general inverse Laplace transform may be difficult we can compute the inverse numerically.
Here an example Python script with $f(t)=4t(1-t)$ and $k=\frac{1}{2}$:
import mpmath as mp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mp.mp.dps = 20
mp.mp.pretty = True

def F(s):
    return 4*(s-2)/s**3

def U_fun(s, z):
    """
    Laplace transformed
    """
    return F(s) * mp.exp(-z * mp.sqrt(k**2 + s**2))

k = mp.mpf('0.5')

t = np.linspace(0, 1, 51)
z = np.linspace(0, 1, 51)

t[0] = 1e-9

T, Z = np.meshgrid(t, z)
U = np.zeros(T.shape)

for i in range(U.shape[0]):
    for j in range(U.shape[1]):
        U[i,j] = mp.invertlaplace(lambda s: U_fun(s, Z[i,j]), T[i,j], method='dehoog')

# Visualize
plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(T, Z, U)
ax.set_xlabel('t')
ax.set_ylabel('z')
ax.set_zlabel('u(t,z)')
plt.grid()

plt.show()



Thank you so much for the answer! Only question, where did you find that the form of the inverse Laplace transform of $e^{-z\sqrt{s^2+k^2}}$?

@GabrielYbarraMarcaida Maple CAS told me.

Are you sure that that's correct? What command did you input in Maple? invlaplace(exp(-z*sqrt(k^2 + s^2)), s, t) ? I just can't replicate it!

@GabrielYbarraMarcaida You need assumptions: assume(k>0);assume(z>0);
